# Select all team data from a drop down

Tags: nodes

I have a drupal form  with a drop down list of teams like team A, team B, Team C and on submit it goes to page `/team-page/[team-id]` and displays the particular team details.So how do I do if I have to select all team data? because my page only accepts team ids and I want to use `/team-page/all`.

Comment: No need to select all team data, you need to create a **default page(/team-page/all)**, by default it will load all the teams. When user submit without selecting any of the teams then it will redirect to **/team-page/all**. And also you can make **all** as the default value in the **select list**, when ever the user submit the form all teams information will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

if your teams data are coming from the same table use drupal db select and table api to create a table where u can see all the data 
try to ajust that to your system

```
  /**
 * Render a filtered list of entries in the database.
 *
 * DBTNG also helps processing queries that return several rows, providing the
 * found objects in the same query execution call.
 *
 * This function queries the database using a JOIN between users table and the
 * example entries, to provide the username that created the entry, and creates
 * a table with the results, processing each row.
 *
 * SELECT
 *  e.pid as pid, e.name as name, e.surname as surname, e.age as age
 *  u.name as username
 * FROM
 *  {dbtng_example} e
 * JOIN
 *  users u ON e.uid = u.uid
 * WHERE
 *  e.name = 'John' AND e.age > 18
 *
 * @see db_select()
 * @see http://drupal.org/node/310075
 */
function dbtng_example_advanced_list() {
  $output = '';

  $select = db_select('dbtng_example', 'e');
  // Join the users table, so we can get the entry creator's username.
  $select->join('users', 'u', 'e.uid = u.uid');
  // Select these specific fields for the output.
  $select->addField('e', 'pid');
  $select->addField('u', 'name', 'username');
  $select->addField('e', 'name');
  $select->addField('e', 'surname');
  $select->addField('e', 'age');
  // Filter only persons named "John".
  $select->condition('e.name', 'John');
  // Filter only persons older than 18 years.
  $select->condition('e.age', 18, '>');
  // Make sure we only get items 0-49, for scalability reasons.
  $select->range(0, 50);

  // Now, loop all these entries and show them in a table. Note that there is no
  // db_fetch_* object or array function being called here. Also note that the
  // following line could have been written as
  // $entries = $select->execute()->fetchAll() which would return each selected
  // record as an object instead of an array.
  $entries = $select->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if (!empty($entries)) {
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
      // Sanitize the data before handing it off to the theme layer.
      $rows[] = array_map('check_plain', $entry);
    }
    // Make a table for them.
    $header = array(t('Id'), t('Created by'), t('Name'), t('Surname'), t('Age'));
    $output .= theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('No entries meet the filter criteria (Name = "John" and Age > 18).'));
  }
  return $output;
}
```